# In NBA, why praising an opponent's player an offense?

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

[Lakers fined $50k after Johnson praises Antetokounmpo](http://sports.inquirer.net/283005/sports-la-lakers-earvin-johnson-magic-johnson-milwaukee-bucks-giannis-antetokounmpo-nba-fines-all-star)

Johnson was quoted as saying.

> “In his understanding of the game, his basketball IQ, his creativity
>   of shots for his teammates. That’s where we [have the] same thing,”
>
> “He’s special. A man that can handle the basketball like he can and be
>   a great — he’s probably the greatest athlete we have in the league
>   today. And then his understanding, his basketball IQ is off the
>   chart.”

Why is it prohibited to praise your opponent? I can't find the rules relating to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This has to do with illegal recruiting**

> The league said in a statement Johnson had breached the NBA’s **[anti-tampering rule](https://basketball.realgm.com/article/246574/CBA-Encyclopedia-Tampering)** in remarks about Antetokounmpo made in an interview with ESPN last week.

The NBA right or wrong feels these statements are intended to influence Antetokounmpo's decision to either stay in Milwaukee or move to LA. This is what the NBA claims and if true violates the CBA(collective bargaining agreement), but I don't see anything in the quote that I think would influence him.... maybe Milwaukee complained?

Comment: I know this is an older answer, but some additional context relating to Magic Johnson may be useful.  Beyond the Giannis tampering fine, Magic was accused of tampering with Ben Simmons, was warned (and the team was fined) for tampering with Paul George, and has been accused of tampering with Anthony Davis.  So he's most likely not getting the benefit of the doubt that others may.